How to order product for key exists?
I'm trying to order the woocommerce products by the existence of a specific meta key, in particular: I need to display first the products that have this meta key, and the all the products that doesn't have the meta key "price_sale_custom", so I wrote this code:
$args['meta_query'][] = [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'promo_exists' => [
        'key'     => 'price_sale_custom',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ],
    'promo_not_exists' => [
        'key'     => 'price_sale_custom',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ],
];

$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['meta_key'] = 'price_sale_custom';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';

the main issue is that I get only the products that have the meta key "price_sale_custom" but not the others that doesn't have it. What I did wrong?
update
$args['meta_query'][] = [
      'relation' => 'OR',
      [
        'key'     => 'price_sale_custom',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
      ],
      [
        'key'     => 'price_sale_custom',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
      ],
    ];

    $args['orderby'] = [
      'price_sale_custom' => 'DESC',
      'date' => 'DESC'
    ];


The meta_key parameter tells WP_Query to only return posts that have the price_sale_custom meta data. Remove that first, and then change orderby to reference the meta_query values:

This is something that WordPress added support for in 4.2: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745334/how-to-order-by-multiple-meta-keys

Thanks for the answer, I tried as you said but isn't working, check my update.

The format is incorrect. Check the other answer again.
